# PHP: How much slower is glob() vs listing specific files?

Tags: php

I have quite a few `*.class.php` files in my `/classes` directory. As the application is updated, these may change, more may be added, and some may be removed.

I have a file that is loaded every page load which includes all necessary files. Right now, I am doing this:

```
$files = glob($site->settings->root_path.'/classes/*.{php}', GLOB_BRACE);

foreach ($files as $file) {
  require_once($file);
}
```

Is this much slower than specifying each file individually? Like:

```
require_once('/path/to/file1.php');
require_once('/path/to/file2.php');
require_once('/path/to/file3.php');
```

The reason I ask is because I think I remember something from a while back that led me to believe that iterating through files/folders was a painfully slow process, but I have no way of knowing for sure.

EDIT: If anyone has a better suggestion than `glob`, I'd be happy for the input.

Comment: _Is this much slower than specifying each file individually?_ Yes, yes it is...  But easy to test.

Comment: Much slower in terms of several ms? Maybe, yes. But why care? You anyway should use an autoloader.

Comment: An autoloader is much better, especially since you're on the verge of micro-optimisation. Selectively autoloading the classes you need will be much better than blindly importing them all.

Comment: As other commenters have said, use [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

Comment: Yes, can confirm I used to do it this way then switched to autoloading. Life was complete then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your question: yes, it will definitely be slower, just because you first have to get the list of files, and then execute `require_once`, that will make another access to file system to check if the file actually exists.

But this is a wrong way to do in my opinion. What you're trying to do is achieved with [autoloading](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Basically, you have to define a function which will try to load a file from a file system, when a script wants to access a class that is not defined. This function then maps the name of the class (with namespaces) to a file on a file system and tries to load it. This way you don't have to worry about how many files you have in your folder, and how often they are added or removed.

Comment: Thank you. I will look over it- this sounds like what I need to implement. It just seems a bit confusing to me right now.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what's already here, the PHP documentation for autoloading has the following snippet (slightly edited however) which should fit what you're doing perfectly.

```
function my_autoloader($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

If you, for example, have a class called ClassA in classes/ClassA.php, simply construct ClassA as you would if you had manually required it. It should work as it would otherwise. Hope that helps!